set Add Order Note checkbox checked by default
Using the Woocommemrce Checkout block, I would like to have the Add Order Note box checked by default. Using jQuery/JS does not seem to work inside the new(ish) block version of the Checkout page.
Code example:
jQuery(function ($) {
  $("#checkbox-control-1").attr("checked", true);
});

I am guessing the Checkout block requires a different approach; the textarea appears to be complete removed from the DOM until the box is checked, and the checkbox never has any 'checked' attribute added/removed when clicked.


Checkout Blocks are React powered, so custom JavaScript will not work on the fields. Only Classic Checkout (shortcode) allow customizations.

Your Code:
jQuery(function ($) {
$("#checkbox-control-1").attr("checked", true);
});

My Code:
jQuery(function ($) {
$("#checkbox-control-1").prop("checked", true);
});

.attr() is used to get or set attributes directly, but for boolean properties like checked, .prop() is preferred because it reflects the current state of the DOM element.
